# Vue table display subrow display issue

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, html-table

Hello all i have nested table data that displays eticket data

```
   <template v-if="isEticket">
              <tr v-for="(row, index) in Rows" :key="'etckt' + index">
                 <template v-for="(rowCol, rowColKey) in row">
                    <template v-if="rowColKey == 'providerName' || rowColKey == 'pnr' || rowColKey == 'pnrStatuses' || rowColKey == 'order'">
                      <td :rowspan="row.rowSpanCount">...some iterations</td>
                    </template>
                 </template>

                 <template v-for="subRow in row.eticketsArr">
                    <td :key="'eticket' + subRow.id">{{ subRow.eticket }}</td>
                    <td :key="'status' + subRow.id">{{ subRow.status }}</td>
                    <td :key="'psgr' + subRow.id">{{ subRow.passenger }}</td>
                    <td :key="'amount' + subRow.id">{{ subRow.amount }}</td>
                    <td :key="'rvamount' + subRow.id">{{ subRow.reverseAmount }}</td>
                    <td :key="'currency' + subRow.id">EUR</td>
                    <td :key="'dt' + subRow.id">{{ subRow.dateTime }}</td>
                    <td :key="'rdt' + subRow.id">{{ subRow.reverseDateTime }}</td>
                    <td :key="'ddt' + subRow.id">{{ subRow.departureDateTime }}</td>
                    <td :key="'opt' + subRow.id">{{ subRow.optionDateTime }}</td>
                    <td :key="'usrmail' + subRow.id">{{ subRow.userEmail }}</td>
                 </template>
              </tr>
           </template>
```

everything is rendered correctly but table view is not correct i tried some ways but didn't achieve correct display.

[image: display1]

[image]

As you see upbelow first display renders all td tags side by side i need to display subrows as sub tr tag thanks for the answers , (second picture is older working version of code)